# Easyslider 1.7 help - all content displaying on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, easyslider

In implementing Easy Slider 1.7 with jQuery on a page of mine, I find that when the page first loads, both images in the `ul` slider display and then the slider loads properly and only the first slide is displayed.

What is the best way to correct this so that the slider `div` doesn't display until the script has loaded properly? I'm using this code to run it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $("#slider").easySlider({
        auto: true,
        continuous: true,
        pause: 10000
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just hide the content via CSS, like this:

```
#slider { display: none; }
```

Then show it on page load as well:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#slider").show().easySlider({ auto: true, continuous: true, pause: 10000 });
});
```

To be safe I'd add a block to the page for non-JS users, could be a style sheet inside if you have a lot of these, otherwise just a style tag:

```
<noscript><style type="text/css">#slider { display: block; }</style></noscript>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added the code below to my css to hide the images from being stacked up.

```
/*Added to hide stacking of images on IE 7/8*/
#slider{
  height:227px;
  overflow:hidden;
}
```