# Easy Slider 1.7 having an issue, please help me

Tags: jquery, css, slider

I am working at a site http://thesunkissedgirls.com.au/

and using Easy Slider 1.7, but i am having trouble that when i refeash the page all slider load underneath the first slider and then start.

I am using this piece of code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $("#slider").easySlider({
            auto: true, 
            continuous: true,
            numeric: true,
            speed: 500,
            pause: 5000,
            controlsShow: false
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

please help me to fix this bug.

thank you.

Comment: Please post your html and jquery code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a small delay before the slider is initialized. You could try to hide all images but the first one before the slider is initialized:

Something like `$('#slider li:not(:first)').hide();` should do the trick.
Don't forget to show them again once the slider has been initialized. 
Same could be done using CSS and a body class.

**UPDATE**
Here's what I would try:

Add a class to the container and the first list element:

```
<div id="slider" class="loading">
    <ul>
        <li class="first">
            <a href="http://thesunkissedgirls.com.au/models">
                <img src="http://thesunkissedgirls.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2011/06/slider_262.jpg" alt="slide1" />
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
        […]
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Add a bit of CSS to hide all but the first element if the wrapper has a `.loading` class:

```
#slider.loading li { display: none; }
#slider.loading li.first { display: block; }
```

And finally remove the `.loading` class once everything is set–up:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $("#slider")
            .easySlider({
                auto: true, 
                continuous: true,
                numeric: true,
                speed: 500,
                pause: 5000,
                controlsShow: false
            })
            .removeClass('loading');
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: can you please check the codes and give idea! what to do.. because i tried all my best but unable to fix.

Comment: I thought that I did. I've added an update to make things hopefully still clearer.

Comment: thank you very much... i also discover very interesting fix of this issue... and i tried this and its working .. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4237141/easyslider-1-7-help-all-content-displaying-on-page-load) fix

Answer (score 0):

Just put easySlider script close to slider div in the body or better after it.

```
<div id="slider">
        <ul>

<li><a href="?id=1"><img src="images/01.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>

<li><a href="?id=2"><img src="images/02.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>         
<li><a href="?id=3"><img src="images/03.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>

<li><a href="?id=4"><img src="images/04.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>

<li><a href="?id=5"><img src="images/05.jpg" alt="Css Template Preview" /></a></li>         
</ul>

<!--  Slider ends  -->  
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $("#slider").easySlider({
            auto: true, 
            continuous: true,
            controlsShow: true,
            prevId: 'prevBtn',
            nextId: 'nextBtn',
            pause: 5000
        });
    }); 
</script>
```